# Select from dual as one row?

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper

To select many strings from dual as one column. I have tried the solution below and i can live with it, its relatively easy with PL/SQL macros to add "select  from dual". I'm wondering is there any other way to achive this?

```
select 'AAA' as code
          from dual
        union all
        select 'ABQ'
          from dual
        union all
        select 'ACA'
          from dual
        union all   
          from dual
```

Comment: There is no PL/SQL in your example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a single column query there is.  You need a database type that is a table of VARCHAR2, and some always exist in oracle including:

- SYS.KU$_VCNT
- SYS.DBMS_DEBUG_VC2COLL

(and of course you could create your own if you prefer).

Then you can query like this:

```
select * from table (SYS.KU$_VCNT ('AAA','ABQ','ACA'));
```

For a query with more than one column, you would need to create a type specifically for that query, which isn't such a useful option.  But just for completeness this is how you could do it:

```
create type my_obj_t as object(n number, d date, c varchar2(100));
create type my_tab_t as table of my_obj_t;

select * from table (my_tab_t(my_obj_t(1,sysdate,'aaa'),
                              my_obj_t(2,date '2014-12-31','bbb'),
                              my_obj_t(3,sysdate+2,'bbb')));
```

Comment: Awesome answer Tony, Thank you. Is there any other embedded table types for numbers, boolean etc?

Comment: @AliArdaOrhan - I'm sure there must be, but I don't currently know them!